# How can i remove shipping.phtml from cart page on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, xml

I try to remove shipping.phtml from cart page [image: shipping.phtml]

I tried to diseable this field from `module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
 <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="cart/shipping.phtml" after="checkout.cart.summary.title">
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping" remove="true" />
```

by adding `<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping" remove="true" />` , but it dosen't work.

Does anyone know if it's another way do disable this phtml?

Answer (score 1):

Add **checkout_cart_index.xml** file in your custom module at **app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

add below code to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: i did this, and after, everything on the cart page dissper

Comment: please check is there any error? developer mode enable

Comment: You don't need to include the `layout` attribute and `update` handles, other than that this should remove that block.

Comment: updated code check it

Comment: @PrashantValanda, I need to remove only shipping methods auto applying in cart page, how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by adding: in Magento_Checkout/layoyut/checkout_index_index.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!--Remove fields-->
                                                                <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>

                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html